# How to update multiple rows with different values in each column

Tags: mysql

old date is already present in the table new date are i want to update

[image: I want to update olddate into new date]

Comment: Please be clear. Is there any error? Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to update a olddate column using new date column

Comment: Do you want to put new date value in old date column ?

Comment: yes i want to doto

Answer (score 1):

this should be a straight `update`.

```
update tableA set `old date` = `update date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

```
update table_name set olddate= case when jmt_id = 1 then newdate else '2019-11-28' end
```

Comment: i want to update multiple row,each row have differnt values

Comment: what values? based on a condition? what condition?

Comment: condition based on jtm_id

Answer (score 0):

try this one to update multiple rows using different values.

```html
update table_name set `old date` = `update date` where 'JTM_id' IN (1265, 1355, 1604)
```

or try this one using jtm_id where condition.

```html
  UPDATE table_name SET 'old date' =2019-10-10 00:00:00 
    where 'JTM_id' IN (1265, 1355, 1604)
```

or try this one to update date

```html
UPDATE table_name SET 'update date' =2019-10-10 00:00:00 
    where 'JTM_id' IN (1265, 1355, 1604)
```

Comment: old date also have different values

Comment: see above i given table

Comment: please try this one to update new date

UPDATE table_name SET 'update date' =2019-10-10 00:00:00 where 'JTM_id' IN (1265, 1355, 1604)